# Cyclic prime groups

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

can I have a refrence to an introduction (not super beginner level, one after) of the multiplicative group $Z/ZP$? I know that it is cyclic. I am interested in known properties of the generators.

Whenever I try to look stuff up I end up on another proof of it being cyclic.

Thankls (hopefully this question is okay for math exchange).

Comment: By properties of the generators you mean something like how to find them?

Comment: This is pretty vague...what sorts of properties did you have in mind?  [Artin's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) seems natural and sensible, but of course it is just a conjecture.

Comment: See *Multiplicative Structure*  in the  notice from  Wikipedia about [Finite fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Multiplicative_structure)

Comment: @lulu Artin's conjecture is exactly what I'm interested in, but like you said, it's a conjecture. So I'm hoping to see some results we know of.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That interests me in general, but not in this case.

Comment: Then what sort of properties do you mean? They are just the generators of a cyclic group of the given order.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Some questions that came up: how to show that there is always a generator under p/k for a constant k, infinitely many primes for which phi(p-1) is very large, so for example if we know there are infinitely many p so that p-1 is a semiprime that'd be great.

Comment: The first question is intimately related to how to find generators, and the second seems to be completely unrelated to the generators of this group.

Comment: [this article](http://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/moree/surva.pdf) linked to from the wikipedia page seems to give a solid survey of what's known. which is very little.  Artin follows from GRH (as discussed in that survey article).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always look up on Keith Conrad expository paper on the cyclicity of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicFp.pdf

Or if you are interested in a more rigorous treatment, the excellent book of Ireland and Rosen, **A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory** has a chapter entirely devoted to the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I read the paper, it is too basic. Thanks for the book recommandation!